# Repeating a request (with Burp Suite or similar tool)

Tags: http, oauth, burp

I have an app that uses OAuth to let users sign in with Linkedin.

There's an issue where the app or browser is sending two OAuth requests to linkedin in quick succession, which causes LinkedIn to return two responses within milliseconds of each other.

The two duplicate requests end up creating two users in the DB.

The main protection here will be to add DB-side validations to prevent this, but would love to be able to re-produce this issue first.

I'm using Burp Suite to intercept the request back to my app. Once I have the request intercepted, how do I replay the request twice within milliseconds of each other?

Additionally, is there a better way to intercept a returning request and replay it quickly to reproduce my issue?

Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

You could do it in Burp Suite with the intruder. You could send the request to the intruder module (right click on the request and "send to intruder") Then you can select one character in an unimportant header, because the intruder has to change something in the request to make him repeat it.
After that, in the payloads tab, add the value that you selected in the payload position, to the payload options list. This way Burp will send two requests, the original, and one with the value you added (but if you use the same value then it is going to be essentially the same).

If all is ready, then start the intruder with the "start attack" in the "intruder" menu.

Answer (score 4):

Repeat request in a loop
Burp Intruder can do various kinds of fuzzing attacks with provided payloads. And the Burp repeater can repeat requests. However if you need to repeat a certain request in a loop again and again then here is the technique to do it. This is done through the Burp Intruder with "Null payloads".

1. Select your request in the Proxy tab and click "Send to Intruder".
2. In Intruder, in the Positions tab click "Clear" to clear all positions. We do not want to provide payloads for any position, just repeat the request.
3. In the Payloads tab, select Payload type : "Null payloads". In the next section of "Payload Options" select "Continue indefinitely". This will generate infinite number of payloads but since we have not specified any position, the payload will not be applied anywhere in the request. If you want to repeat the request for a specific number of times then put a number in the "Generate _____ payloads" box. It will then loop only that many times.

4.Then Start Attack.